# Upload file to SharePoint online with HTTP REST calls

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, postman

According to the following link:

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

I can add a file using

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)
method: POST
body: "Contents of file"
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-length:length of post body
```

I am testing this with Postman. In my post request I set the body to form-data and add a file parameter with a text file called "a.txt". The text file contains the text:

```
one
two
three
```

When I execute my request in Postman my text file is present in SharePoint. When I open the file on SharePoint the contents of the file is:

```
----------------------------235004993628819232914336
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

one
two
three
----------------------------235004
```

I want to do this action by only using plain HTTP calls. Is this behaviour correct? It looks like a file is created and the content is filled with my formdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the body to binary in Postman fixed my problem. Key is setting the correct content-length otherwise the file will get corrupted.

Get the content length of thee file with PowerShell

```
$file = "c:\temp\file.docx"
(Get-Item $file).Length
```